# Why is a jsonpath query for a key much slower than for a value when using a gin index in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonpath

I have a PostgreSQL 14 database using a GIN index on a jsonb column to allow jsonpath queries.
However, it seems that searching for JSON keys like this:

```
select *
from t
where 
"myColumn" @?? ('$.** ? ( exists(@."abc") )')
```

is much slower than searching for JSON values like this:

```
select *
from t
where 
"myColumn" @?? ('$.** ? ( @.* == "abc" )')
```

How can I improve the performance when searching for JSON keys?

Comment: To be able of tune up a query is necessary the query execution plan `explain (analyze, buffers) select ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first formulation corresponds to the "2nd kind" in the below, from 'src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb_gin.c':

```
 * [...] jsonb_ops might also support statements of the 2nd kind,
 * but given we have no statistics keys extracted from accessors chain
 * are likely non-selective.  Therefore, we choose to not confuse optimizer
 * and skip statements of the 2nd kind altogether.  In future versions that
 * might be changed.
```

So it sounds like they didn't implement because they didn't think it was worth implementing.

Comment: I trust in this answer. Too bad :(